# Email confirmation with nodemailer is not working in production ( Heroku )

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, mongoose, nodemailer

I am using MERN stack and I have created email confirmation for registered users. Everything is working on localhost, but then I try to confirm my email on production environment, nothing happens. It seems that heroku is not reaching that page, because console.log is not showing up in Heroku logs from confirmation page. 
Here is my server.js file

```js
const express = require('express');
const connectDB = require('./config/db');
const compression = require('compression');
const enforce = require('express-sslify');

const app = express();
// Connect Database
connectDB();

// Init Middleware
app.use(express.json());

// Define Routes
app.use('/api/users', require('./routes/api/users'));
app.use('/api/confirmation', require('./routes/api/confirmation'));
app.use('/api/auth', require('./routes/api/auth'));

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  app.use(compression());
  app.use(enforce.HTTPS({ trustProtoHeader: true }));
  app.use(express.static('client/build'));

  app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'));
  });
}

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000;

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server started on port ${PORT}`));
```

. 
In user.js file I am creating a user and sending an email with user id ( id is correct, as in mongoDB ) 
This is my user.js file

```js
router.post(
  '/',
  async (req, res) => {
    const { name, email, password, role } = req.body;
    try {
      let user = await User.findOne({ email });
      if (user) {
        return res
          .status(400)
          .json({ errors: [{ msg: 'User already exists' }] });
      }
      user = new User({
        name,
        email,
        avatar,
        password,
        role
      });
      const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
      user.password = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);
      await user.save();
      let url = null;  
      if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
        url = `https://myherokuapp/api/confirmation/${user.id}`
      } else {
        url = `http://localhost:4000/api/confirmation/${user.id}`
      }

      transporter.sendMail({
        to: email,
        subject: 'Confirm Email',
        html: `Please click this link to confirm your email: <a href="${url}">${url}</a>`,
      })
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
      res.status(500).send('Server error');
    }
  }
);
```

Than I open the confirmation link from gmail, it goes to the - myherokuapp.com/api/confirmation/userId and redirects into the main page - myherokuapp.com, but user.confirmed is still the same - false.

This is my confirmation.js file

```js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const User = require('../../models/User');

router.get('/:id', async (req, res) => {

  let userId = req.params.id;

  let conditions = {
    _id : userId
  }
  let update = {
    confirmed: true
  }
  try {
    const user = await User.findOneAndUpdate(conditions,update, {
      new: true
    });
  
      if(user.confirmed){
        if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'){
          return res.redirect('https://myherokuapp.com')
          
        } else {
          return res.redirect('http://localhost:3000');
        }
      } else {
        console.log('error')
      }
    } catch (err){
      console.error(err.message);
      res.status(500).send('Server Error');
    }
   });
  
   module.exports = router;
```

I am dealing with this problem for a couple of days, so I would be very grateful for your help